Using Named Credentials for WhatsApp authentication with permanent token
To connect SF with WhatsApp, namely to send messages on WhatsApp, I used permanent token generated on the WhatsApp side. I saved it in protected custom setting (in the future there will be a managed package).
Accordingly, I used this permanent token in the callout method:
request.setHeader ('Authorization', 'Bearer' + customSetting.PermanentToken).
And received an issue with SF Code Analyzer ApexSuggestUsingNamedCred. So, you remember: I have only permanent token.
Later, I tried to create Named Credential:
When creating NC, I entered the value permanent token in the password field. And then I used Named Credential for callout. And in the setHeader method, I used the value '{!$Credential.Password}':

Apart from the fact that I actually used Named Credentials, the error with the SF Code Analyzer remained: ApexSuggestUsingNamedCred still complained.

Redo your implementation based on External Credential, you'll be able to save your permanent token there and construct the header with it.

This question is similar to: How do you correctly populate an External Credential from a Principal for a Named Credential?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
